# Do i need to declare receiver in adroidxmlfile using register receiver?

Tags: android, android-manifest

For this code, as I'm using `LocalBroadcastManager`:

```
 LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mMessage, new IntentFilter("timer"));

        mMessage = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int t = intent.getIntExtra("time", 0);
        tv.setText(t+"");
    }
 };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to register the receiver in the Manifest file.
Register the receiver in the onResume() method by calling registerReceiver() method.
Don't forget to unregister the receiver in the onPause() method by calling unregisterReceiver().

Answer (score 2):

No, You do not need to define it in `manifest.xml` file. It is a good practice and recommended that you register your `Receiver` in `onResume()` method and also unregister it by calling `unregisterReceiver` method in `onPause()` method of your activity.